# Notification not showing with alarmmanager

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm trying to show a notification in 5 seconds that my app starts. After some debugging I found that `BroadcastReceiver` never gets called. This is what I have:

Manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.seppe.momentum7">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".HomeActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".AndroidDatabaseManager"></activity>
        <receiver
            android:name=".BroadcastManager"
            android:label="BroadcastReceiverAux">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.seppe.momentum7" /> --!!--!!--

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
</manifest>
```

HomeActivity.java:

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener( onNavigationItemSelectedListener);

        boolean alarm = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent("ALARM"), PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) == null);

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: alarm = "+ alarm);

        if(alarm){

            AlarmManager alarme = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 5);

            Intent itAlarm = new Intent(".DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION");
            itAlarm.setClass(this, HomeActivity.class);
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: intent = " + itAlarm);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,100,itAlarm,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                alarme.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
            }
            else {
                alarme.setTime(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
            }
        }
    }
```

BroadcastManager.java:

```
    public class BroadcastManager extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "BroadcastManager";
    public static final String CHANNEL_1_ID = "channel1";
    public static final String CHANNEL_2_ID = "channel2";
    private NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager;
    private static Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        createNotificationChannels();

        mContext = context;

        notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(mContext);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, CHANNEL_1_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("notification")
            .setContentText("this is a notification")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
            .build();

        notificationManager.notify(1, notification);

    }

    private void createNotificationChannels() {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            NotificationChannel channel1 = new NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_1_ID,
                "channel 1",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            );
            channel1.setDescription("this is channel 1");

            NotificationChannel channel2 = new NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_2_ID,
                "channel 2",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            );
            channel2.setDescription("this is channel 2");

            NotificationManager manager = mContext.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel1);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel2);
        }
    }
}
```

---

So the problem is:

- My notification doesn't popup
- Whith some logs I found out that my BroadcastReciever never gets called

What I think the problem is:

- I think the problem is in my manifest file at the line with "--!!--!!--". Because I haven't found out for what it is and what possibilities I have to fill in there.

What I have tried:

- A lot of different tutorials

If you need more information or something else feel free to comment.

Comment: You should be using an explicit `Intent` for your alarm broadcast. Remove the `<intent-filter>` altogether. Then use `new Intent(this, BroadcastManager.class)` for the alarm `Intent`s. I would also point out that the `PendingIntent` you're using to check if the alarm needs to be set does not match the `PendingIntent` you're actually using for the alarm. Both should use the `Intent` I just suggested, and the `requestCode`s – i.e., the second arguments in the `getBroadcast()` calls – need to match. Also, you don't need the `SET_ALARM` permission for this.

Comment: This is my answer :) Thank you very much!! I think the problem was with the `intent-filter`. And thanks for pointing out the rest of it.